# In the iOS app show answers below the question

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

I can't understand why answers to a question are separated from the question? Why should I have to press an extra button to show answers to a question? I think it would be better to place them just under the question like in the browser version.

Comment: This is a problem that the mobile version of the website is very good, so its hard for the iOS/android app to improve on that

Comment: This also goes for the Android version, so it's hard to believe they didn't have a reason for doing so.

Comment: My guess would be lower bandwidth, plus the ability to swap back and forth without losing your scroll position on each side